# Selenium, finding a span with specific text inside a specific div by its xpath?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a div, let's say it's id is div1, and I need to find a span inside that div, let's say it contains `spanText` as its text. How can I do this? I've tried the following but so far no luck.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='div1']a/span[contains(text(), 'spanText')]")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the letter 'a' in your XPath supposed to be?

Comment: Also, post sample of relevant HTML.

Answer (score 5):

As @Siking already correctly pointed out, you have a typo in your XPath. You probably need to add a slash (assuming the span element is inside the `a` element):

```
//div[@id='div1']/a/span[contains(text(), 'spanText')] 
             HERE^
```

Or, you can just look for the span anywhere inside the `div`:

```
//div[@id='div1']//span[contains(text(), 'spanText')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking that website **[xpather.com](http://xpather.com/)**,

it show you first if you're xpath has no errors

and if you're xpath is correct, it shows you if it find elements in the given html element